# When is a question too philosphical?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In general I would like to know if there is some criteria to consider certain thought experiments or questions to be better suited for philosophical discussion rather than physics discussion.

The question [Is a Thomson's lamp physically realistic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146794/2451) has been put on hold for being off topic. I am not clear why that is the case?

I understand that the question is philosophically motivated but I think it is suitable for physical considerations.

One can answer the question in a non philosophical manner. The question ask for some physical argumentation in favour or against a possible outcome  in a thought experiment. Even, the possibility of the thought experiment can  be argued on physical grounds.

The answer to this question would require to at least elaborate in the following topics:

Experimental designs and results

Accepted and/or actively researched theories

However, there are some other questions (e.g. [Did spacetime start with the Big bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5150/did-spacetime-start-with-the-big-bang) 
) which I will regard as highly philosophical but again I understand them being open as all the answers are in some sense physics oriented.

I am asking to consider the reopening of the former question, but as a second plea. My main request is if someone would mind to point me some general guideline about when is a question too philosophical and not suitable for the site. Even if the guidelines are time dependent.

Comment: Thumb rule: If a question sounds philosophical *at all*, it is probably *too philosophical*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the case that 5 individual contributors to this site decided to close this question.  This is a fact.

Essentially, everything else is irrelevant.

It very well may be the case that, on a different day (month, year), this question would not be closed.

This site (composed of moderators, contributors with voting rights etc.) is not time invariant.

Finally, regardless of what you think *ought* to be the case, if essentially no one here is interested in the question, it doesn't matter if it is closed or not.

So, bottom line, it isn't the policy *per se*; it is up to *the OP* to phrase the question in a way that is interesting *enough* to those that contribute here *at this particular time*.

I could say more but it is late.  I'll refine and amplify later.

> Would you mind expanding a little bit on how can I phrase the question
>   in a way that is interesting enough to those that contribute here at
>   this particular time

I assume you're referring to the Thomson's lamp question.  If the question is about a genuine philosophical *puzzle*, it is certainly beyond the scope of physics to decide.

Put another way, if physics can decide the problem, the problem isn't a philosophical puzzle.

As an aside, in your question, you write:

> The sum of this infinite series of time intervals is **exactly** two
>   minutes.

I intentionally emphasized the word *exactly*.  Think about the *physical* implication of *that* in relation to this puzzle.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. Would you mind expanding a little bit on how can I phrase the question in a way that is interesting enough to those that contribute here at this particular time.